# What is the "A" button on the PC?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I'm trying to finish the deckers.die mission on the PC.  When I get to the boss fight, it tells me to mash the "A" button.  I hit the "A" key, and that doesn't work.  The few times it tells me to hit "Space" that does work.  So, I know my timing is good.

I looked through the Control bindings, and I don't see it.  I do see in the gamepad section, that the default "A" button action is to jump, which is the same as "Space" on the PC.  Is that what I should be hitting?

So, my question is, What is the "A" button on the PC?

----- edit

When I hit Esc to get to the menu, one of the choices is highlighted with a green "A" beside it, like in the fight.  <strike>Hitting "Space" does nothing.  So, that's not it.</strike>

----- 2nd edit

As my answer below says, "Space" did work during the actual in-game fight

Comment: It looks as though you've answered your own question, if hitting the space key, which is mapped to jump then one would suspect that space == A

Comment: Updated my question.  That doesn't appear to hold as I'd hoped it would

Comment: Do you have a controller plugged in?  I just played this part a couple days ago and was prompted for `SPACE` and mouse buttons.

Comment: No, I do not have a controller plugged in.  During the fight, when my character crawls on his back, it usually asked for A, but sometimes Space.  If I made it past that first stage, then it usually asked for Rt, but sometimes a mouse button.  In the section vs the guards, there were special attacks that used Left and Right that I never figured out how to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cole was right.  In the fight, the "A" button and the jump button are the same thing.  Also, the "Rt" button that it asks for a lot is primary fire.  (I think.  Just had to reboot, so haven't tested it, yet.)  You can go into the Controls and look at the Gamepad scheme to check for any others.

<strike>Kind of annoying that they don't make allowances for people who are *not* playing on a console.</strike>

Edit:

As usual, it was User Error.  About six months ago I was trying to get FaceTrackNoIR to work with XPlane.  At that time, one route to do that was to install VJoy, a virtual joystick.

Even though I had both virtual joysticks disabled, Saints Row was picking them up, and treated them as controllers.  I just uninstalled VJoy and Saints Row is now a well-behaved PC program.

Comment: I think the most annoying part would be, that they were pretty inconsistent with the button display. One part is hard-coded (showing `A`) while another part is dynamic (showing `Space`). It's similar to how in other games it says `Press Ctrl` but you **know** you don't have anything mapped to that button, until you realize that the `Ctrl` button was part of the standard key mapping.

Comment: @Nolonar - try playing a game like Sonic 4 on the PC where -no matter what button you assign- it just shows colours to represent those buttons. "Press the [Red] button now!" style

Comment: Space didn't work out at the menu.  It did work in the fight